# Why could plain string be used as filehandle?

Tags: perl

I understand bareword could be used as filehandle as the first line below, even if it is not recommended, but it seems the second line also work. Why does plain string work as filehandle?

```
perl -E"open FH, 'somefile.txt' or die 'open failed';print <FH>"
perl -E"open 'FH', 'somefile.txt' or die 'open failed';print <FH>"
```

**UPDATE**: if bareword FH is the same as plain string 'FH', why the below line doesn't work?

```
perl -E"open FH, 'somefile.txt';print <'FH'>"
```

Comment: Perl does a lot of stuff that exist for legacy reasons and compatibility. That doesn't mean it's a good idea to use it - both for code maintainability, but also your own sanity.

Comment: Indeed! One shouldn't be using either of those. Stop using globals and use lexicals like everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks. I will avoid using these patterns, just interested to make sense from grammar and syntax side.

Comment: @ikegami I always appreciate being corrected. this message too.

Comment: Regarding your update, noone said bareword `FH` is the same thing as string literal `'FH'`. They're not, as you've demonstrated and as the following demonstrates: `perl -E'sub foo { "abc" } print "foo"."\n".foo."\n";'`. A bareword simply acts as a string literal if no other meaning is found. In the particular case you are asking about, Perl checks if a bareword was provided to determine whether `<...>` means `readline(...)` or `glob(...)`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following two statements are identical (if there's no sub named `FOO`):

```
my $x = FOO;
my $x = 'FOO';
```

So, it's not really that surprising that the following are equivalent:

```
open FH, ...
open 'FH', ...
```

The same goes for

```
print { FH } ...
print { 'FH' } ...
```

and for

```
readline(FH)
readline('FH')
```

---

Note that the following are not equivalent

```
print FH ...
print 'FH' ...
```

because the parser specifically looks if a bareword was provided to `print` determine the meaning the arguments.

```
print LIST           # Prints list to selected handle
print BAREWORD LIST  # Prints list to specified handle
print { EXPR } LIST  # Prints list to specified handle
```

---

Note that the following are not equivalent

```
<FH>
<'FH'>
```

because the parser specifically looks if a bareword is inside of `<>` to determine the meaning the operator.

```
<BAREWORD>   # readline(BAREWORD)
<EXPR>       # glob(EXPR)
```

Comment: This is quite strange. I was going to comment that using `my $x = FOO` will issue a bareword warning, but it did not. However, `my $x = foo` does issue the warning. That is inconsistent, presumably some legacy remnant? (Not my downvote)

Comment: @TLP, The warning isn't for using a bareword as a a string, but for using a lowercase bareword in general since these are reserved by Perl. At least, officially. In reality, a feature is needed to add a new name too all namespaces, lowercase or not. This warning should be abolished. It's `use strict;` that forbids barewords as strings.

Comment: @ikegami seems the parser recognizes bareword and has varies rules to handle it based on the specific context. In most general context, it is converted to string, and specific handling in some other context like it is the first argument for print, or inside <> operator. Is this right?

Comment: Yup, exactly. And seeing how they perform the same function by default, it's best to preserve the relation in other contexts (e.g. `open`'s first argument) if there's no reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Ask perl parser,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -E"open 'FH', 'somefile.txt' or die 'open failed';print <FH>"

use feature 'current_sub', 'evalbytes', 'fc', 'say', 'state', 'switch', 'unicode_strings', 'unicode_eval';
die 'open failed' unless open *FH, 'somefile.txt';
print <FH>;
```

So it doesn't use string but typeglob after all, but I wouldn't consider that as a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

That file handle isn't really a *bare word*, but a *type glob*. This has to do with how Perl stores *package variables* in a *symbol table*. I don't want to go into symbol tables and how they work, but it's the way Perl can store a reference to the open filehandle.

There are multiple problems with using `open BAR...`. The main one is the ability to pass that *type glob* to a subroutine. Imagine a subroutine where I take an already open file, read through that file, and return the next line that matches the regular expression. How do I pass in the file handle?

```
my $line = grep_me ( BAR, $regex );    # That doesn't quite work.
```

There *is* a way by passing a reference to that *type glob* to scalar variable, but the syntax is obscure and rather messy.

One of the biggest features in Perl 5 is the use of references. If you haven't used Perl references before, take a look at the [tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Try this program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $real_file = "...";    # A real file with that name

open my $foo, "<", $real_file or die $!;
say "\$foo is a $foo";
```

This will print out something like:

```
$foo is a GLOB(0x7feb0c0060e8)
```

This is saying that `$foo` is a *reference* to a *type glob*. Remember I said that you could pass a *type glob* file handle to a subroutine by making a reference to it? Perl 5 already gives you that nice reference which makes passing that file handle very easy:

```
...
my $line = grep_me ( $foo, $regex );
...

sub grep_me {
     my $fh = shift;   # The file handle
     my $re = shift;   # The regular expression

     my $line;
     while ( $line = <$fh> ) {
        last if ( $line =~ /$re/ );
     }
     return $line;
}
```

There are other advantages to using a scalar reference to a file handle too:

- The file handle is lexically scoped, so once `$foo` goes out of scope, the file handle automatically closes.
- Since the file handle is lexically scoped, it's unavailable outside of the file itself. Imagine if I had a module that used a file, if I use `open FOO...`, that file handle is available to the program that uses my module. If I use `open my $foo...`, the program that uses my module can't manipulate the file without going through my module.

Comment: Re "How do I pass in the file handle?" `*BAR`. Re "There is a way by passing a reference to that type glob to scalar variable, but the syntax is obscure and rather messy." Or you could just pass the glob, whose syntax is the same as every other variable (sigil+name).